# JSF2.0 form with submit and edit button

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation

In Jsf-2.1.7 , We have form with two command links , one is submit which should validate the fields ,other is edit link which should skip the validations.

But edit button doesn't skip the bean validation

```
<h:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{buyerBacking.edit}" immediate="true">

    </h:commandLink>
```

Any clues??

Comment: how about removing the `immediate="true"` and adding `<f:ajax/>` inside the `<h:commandLink...><f:ajax/></h:commandLink>` ?

Comment: @Daniel: OP's code would have worked when using standard JSF validation. However, OP explicitly mentioned "bean validation". So OP likely actually means skipping the JSR303 bean validation such as `@NotNull`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the bean validation using [`<f:validateBean disabled="true">`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/validateBean.html). You could check a request parameter for that which is then been set by the command link.

E.g.

```html
<f:validateBean disabled="#{param.disableBeanValidation}" />
...
<h:commandLink ...>
    <f:param name="disableBeanValidation" value="true" />
</h:commandLink>
```